# Listing information in ListView instead of TextView from database - Android

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

I have an activity in my app that lists all the information from my database into a TextView, however I want to print out in a ListView instead. Im unsure how to do this so here is what I have so far.

```
public class ViewMeeting extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText deleteText;
    Button  deleteButton;
    TextView tv;
    List<MeetingModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_meeting);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        deleteText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete1);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(textView6);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        list = db.getAllMeetingsList();
        print(list);
    }
//prints details from database table into a textview
   private void print(List<MeetingModel> list) {

        String value = "";
        for(MeetingModel sm : list){
            value = value+" ID: "+sm.id +"\n" +" Title: "+sm.title +"\n"+"             
            Date: "+sm.date +"\n" + " Time: "+sm.time +"\n" +" Location: 
            "+sm.location+"\n"+"\n";
        }
        tv.setText(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a ListView to your activity's layout. Then in your print function, pass your list of meetings to an ArrayAdapter, then set it as your ListView adapter like below:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, R.layout.LIST_ID, list);

ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.LIST_ID);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**UPDATE**
You code will then look something like:

```
public class ViewMeeting extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText deleteText;
    Button deleteButton;
    TextView tv;
    List < MeetingModel > list = new ArrayList <  > ();
    DatabaseHelper db;
    ArrayList meetings = new ArrayList < String > ();
    ListView listView;
     @ Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_meeting);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.LIST_ID);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        deleteText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        deleteButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delete1);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(textView6);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        list = db.getAllMeetingsList();
        print(list);
    }
    //prints details from database table into a textview
    private void print(List < MeetingModel > list) {

        String value = "";
        for (MeetingModel sm: list) {
            value = value + " ID: " + sm.id + "\n" + " Title: " + sm.title + "\n" + "
                        Date: " + sm.date + "\n" + " Time: " + sm.time + "\n" + " Location:
                        " + sm.location + "\n" + "\n";
            meetings.add(value);
        }
        //tv.setText(value);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, R.layout.LIST_ID, meetings);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting an error on this line:                                          ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, R.layout.LIST_ID, meetings);    ........   Its saying 'Cannot resolve symbol LIST_ID'. Why would this be?

Comment: You should replace LIST_ID with your ListView's ID

Comment: It should not contain any capital letters or "-". Name it as my_list_view for example.

Comment: still doesnt work im afraid. Do i have to have it anywhere else other than this class and the layout?

Answer (score 0):

Search for some Adapters for your ListView as ArrayAdapter

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: This might answer the question, but link only answers are not recommended here. Links can break, so you should at least give a summary of the relevant aspects.